# Primitive Pythagorean triple

Tags: number-theory

[image]

I have no idea how to start proving it.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the prime decompositions of $x',y',z'$ and trying to make their gcds 1?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assume two of $x,y,z$ share a common prime factor, prove the third shares it too, then divide that factor ( squared) out of the equation. You obtain another triple. Repeating the argument, prove that eventually the triple resulting will be a primitive one.

Comment: thanks! but how to prove the third share it too? this is what I have done: assume x,y share a common prime factor, denote it by p. So we can write x=tp and y=sp when t,s are positive integers. x^2+y^2=z^2 =>       p^2(t^2+s^2)=z^2 (so p^2 divides z^2). but after root for the equation we get p*(t^2+s^2)^(1/2)=z so why p is a common prime factor of z? I dont know if *(t^2+s^2)^(1/2) is integer.

Comment: If $p^2$ divides $z^2$, then $p$ divides $z^2$. But $p$ is prime and so, if $p$ divides $ab$, then, either $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. Taking $a = b = z$ you can conclude that $p$ divides $z$.

Comment: Oh right! thanks!